# Does a "sigma.robust" momentFUN passthrough work with both StdDev and ES risk models

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

I am using the wonderful PortfolioAnalytics package in R.

To shrink the covariance matrix I use the "sigma.robust" example. I use the EDHEC data.

I create the initial portfolio, and from that, create the 4 portfolios I intend to compare.

What I want to see is that a) passing the robust covar works - by comparing it to one with and without, and b) that it works with risk models of StdDev and Expected Shortfall.

```
data(edhec)
# Use the first 4 columns in edhec for a returns object
R <- edhec[, 1:4]
colnames(R) <- c("CA", "CTAG", "DS", "EM")
head(R, 5)
funds <- colnames(R)
```

## initialise pf and use some basic constraints

```
init.portf <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="full_investment")
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="box",min = .05,max = .4)
```

## Portfolio with standard deviation as an objective

```
SD.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")
SD.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=SD.portf, type="return", name="mean")
```

## Portfolio with expected shortfall as an objective

```
ES.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="risk", name="ES")
ES.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=ES.portf, type="return", name="mean")
```

## Function for the robust covar

```
sigma.robust <- function(R){
  require(MASS)
  out <- list()
  set.seed(1234)
  out$sigma <- cov.rob(R, method="mcd")$cov
  return(out)
}
```

## pass through the custom function

```
opt.sd_robust <- optimize.portfolio(R, SD.portf,optimize_method="ROI",momentFUN =  "sigma.robust",trace = TRUE)
opt.es_robust <- optimize.portfolio(R, ES.portf,optimize_method="ROI",momentFUN =  "sigma.robust",trace = TRUE)
```

## create the normal portfolios that I intend to contrast the effect against

```
opt.sd <- optimize.portfolio(R, SD.portf,optimize_method="ROI",trace = TRUE)
opt.es <- optimize.portfolio(R, ES.portf,optimize_method="ROI",trace = TRUE)
```

## combine them for easy viewing

```
opt_comb = combine.optimizations(list(opt.sd_robust = opt.sd_robust,opt.es_robust = opt.es_robust,opt.sd = opt.sd,opt.es = opt.es))
```

## plot them

```
chart.Weights(opt_comb,ylim(0,1))
```

## inspect them

```
extractWeights(opt_comb)



                     CA      CTAG  DS   EM
opt.sd_robust 0.08507019 0.1149298 0.4 0.40
opt.es_robust 0.15000000 0.4000000 0.4 0.05
opt.sd        0.05000000 0.1500000 0.4 0.40
opt.es        0.15000000 0.4000000 0.4 0.05
```

## Conclusion

And it does work for the risk model using StdDev. The weights are different. The pass-through has worked. But it doesn't seem to affect the Expected Shortfall model. The weights are identical. I find this is the case even if I relax the box constraint [I'd wondered if I'd rendered any other outcome infeasible, so I tried with and without the constraint].

So I suppose I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I had though ES is just looking in the tail of a distribution that is effectively derived from the transformed covariance matrix.

Thus shrinking/regularising the covar would be compatible with ES.

So I conclude I'm doing something wrong.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.